# How can i make a script to open Winbox Wine easier and faster

Tags: scripts, wine, executable

Now when I tried to open Winbox, I have to :

1. Open Terminal
2. cd /home/xxxx/Downloads
3. wine winbox64.exe

All I want is just put some executable or icon that we can put it at Favorites or Desktop and just one single click and then the Ubuntu will open Winbox for me.

Im using Linux Ubuntu 19.10 now..

really need your help to speed up our activity in Linux

im new linux user

Answer (score 1):

Similar to what I did for running `CloneVDI.exe` with Wine. CloneVDI is an application to clone VirtualBox virtual drives. It works very well in Linux.

The easiest way to add your app as a menu item is by adding the app with `Alacarte` or `Main Menu`. If you don't have it in your Ubuntu, install it with:

```
sudo apt-get install alacarte
```

Then, open it (it may be installed under Accessories).

[image]

The image corresponds to my specific case. Change *Name* and *Command* to your app. You could locate your app with the `Browse` button.

This will add the corresponding `.desktop` file to `$HOME/.local/share/applications`.

[image]

The `CloneVDI` shortcut was saved under the name `alacarte-made-1.desktop`. Copy that file to your `~/Desktop` and you are done!

The desktop file content will look like to something like this:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Comment=
Terminal=false
Name=CloneVDI
Exec=wine /opt/CloneVDI-exe-4.00/CloneVDI.exe
Type=Application
Icon=gnome-panel-launcher
```

I wish it could be easier but this is Linux Desktop world; infinitely hackable.

Comment: wow... thanks for that...

it works like a magic...

now i can just type "windows logo" and type winbox and then it works

but how to put it as favourite so that it will stay at the left bar of ubuntu ?

because when i tried to right click there is no menu as make it a favorite

Comment: What is your Desktop Manager? Mate, Cinnamon, KDE, Gnome, Xfce?

Comment: how to know that ? sorry im newbie at linux..


used to be windows everytime